# Recursion function -counting permuation and ignoring permutation

Tags: c++, recursion, permutation

I am given this problem:

We are going over recursion in my class and I do not quite understand it, I was wondering if someone can help me with this problem

let c(n) be the number of different group integers that can be chosen from the integers **1 through n-1**, so that the integers in each group add up to n (for example, n=4=[1+1+1+1]=[1+1+2]=[2+2]). Write a recursive definition for c(n) under the following variations:

a) You count permutations. For example, 1,2,1 and 1,1,2 are two groups that each add up to 4

b)you ignore permutations

I know permutations is how many ways you can arrange a set of numbers, so is my code below correct? I get an answer of 7?
Here is my code for part a:

```
int recurse (int n);

int main(){
    int a=4;
    int sum_perm;
    sum_perm=recurse(a);
    cout<<sum_perm-1<<endl; 
    //Can I do -1 here because it should be from a group of integers from 1 to n-1?  
return 0;
}

int recurse(int n)
{
    int sum = 1;
    if (n == 1){
        return 1;
  }
      for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
              sum += recurse(n - i); 

   }       
return sum;
}
```

For part B, if I am not counting permutations, what am I counting?
Here is my code for part b:

```
int without (int n, int max);

int main(){
    int a=4, b =3;
    int sum_without;
    sum_without=without(a,b);
    cout<<sum_without<<endl;

system("Pause");
return 0;
}

int without(int n, int max)

{
    if(n == 1 || max == 1){
        return 1;
}               
    else if (n == max){
        return 1 + without(n, n-1);
        }
    else{
        return without(n,max-1) + without(n-max, max);
        }
}
```

Comment: The answer to the only question you have is: When you are ignoring permutations, you are counting combinations. However, that is not a programming question and is not related to the code you have posted.

Comment: @RSahu I posted the function to part a to show I just wasn't looking for someone to do my work for me

Comment: It isn't clear from the post what you are looking for from the SO community.

Comment: I guess how do I edit my code so I am not counting permutations

Comment: Here's some starter code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891477/recursive-function-counting-and-printing-partitions-of-1-to-n-1/28892800#28892800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show any code to generate the combinations of numbers that produce a sum. Link to wiki article about [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) .

In this case, the goal is to count the number of combinations and/or permutations, which might be possible without actually generating a set of combinations. Not sure if recursion helps here, but you can convert any loop into recursion if you pass enough variables.

Example "partitions"

1 combination that sums to 1:

```
1
```

2 combinations that sum to 2:

```
1 1
2
```

3 combinations that sum to 3:

```
1 1 1
1 2
3
```

5 combinations that sum to 4:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 2
1 3
2 2
4
```

7 combinations that sum to 5:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 2
1 4
2 3
5
```

11 combinations of numbers that sum to 6:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 3
1 1 2 2
1 1 4
1 2 3
2 2 2
1 5
2 4
3 3
6
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you, I do not think recursion will help. Our teacher wants us to get practice with recursion so he gave us these questions. I do not think he wants us to output the combinations, just the sum of how many we can make from 1 to n-1. So if I used 6, ignoring permutations, then the answer would be 10

Comment: I have been trying to write a function to print out the partitions and I cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend combinations directly being considered. While it seems like the more difficult case a simple rule makes it trivial.

> Numbers calculated are in decreasing order

This requires you to track the last number, but ensures you don't calculate `1 5` and then `5 1`, as the former is impossible.

Comment: I think that would be easier if I didn't need to use recursion

Comment: @HG319: Why? Just pass in a maximum and start with the original number as a maximum for your first call. Remember recursion doesn't mean recursing using the same function call, you often need two functions, one to provide the outside parameters and another to recurse.

Comment: I have written the function for part b using a max. I am going to post it now. since I have the constraint 1 to n-1 I made the max n-1. It made sense to me but I am still a novice.

Comment: @HG319: If you are splitting 4, then you need to consider the group {4}. You can either do that in the first function (and do as you said) or have your second function do it (and pass n). Either way works. One of the wonderful things about software is there are a lot of ways of doing things, and whatever we pick we usually learn something.

Comment: @HG319: What you suggested is fine.